# In Javascript How do I prevent other functions from being invoked while under the setTimeout duration?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am doing a tic-tac-toe game.

I included a setTimeout function so that before the computer makes its move, it will look like it is "thinking" before the computer actually leaves a mark in the board.

However, I noticed that while the computer is "thinking" I can make my move thereby defeating the purpose of having an opponent make their move first before I can make another of my own (if that makes sense)

Example:

(My turn) I mark a box with circle
(Computer turn) Computer 'thinks'...

- I make a move while computer is thinking
- My move leaves a mark in the board before computer makes its move, meaning a function still gets invoked while under the    setTimeout duration.

How do I prevent this? Is this possible?

```
setTimeout(compTurn, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click listener for when the player takes a turn, check to see if the player is permitted to play first. Toggle a boolean when `compTurn` gets scheduled, and toggle it off when `compTurn` finishes:

```
// Start of game:
let playerTurn = true;

// ...

// Make computer take a turn:

playerTurn = false;
setTimeout(compTurn, 1000);
const compTurn = () => {
  // ...
  playerTurn = true;
};
```

```
board.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!playerTurn) return;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I haven't thought of that.